# How do I use wait() and notify() if I have one Runnable and one that implements Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to start the second thread after the first thread has finished. But I can't figure out how to use the wait()/notify() function if the threads are implemented differently.
Tried first to use it in separate classes, but then I couldn't get the first thread to signal when it was finished.

```
public class Oblig1 {

  static void threadMessage(String message) {
    String threadName =
        Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                      threadName,
                      message);
  }

  private boolean start = false;

  public void StartThread(){
    start = true;
  }

  class Thread1 implements Runnable{
    private int X;
    Thread2 obj = new Thread2(5);

    public Thread1(int x) {
      X = x;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
      for (int i=1; i<21; i++) {
        System.out.print(X*i + " ");

        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
        }
      }

      StartThread();
      notifyAll();
    }
  }

  class Thread2 extends Thread {
    private int X;

    public Thread2(int x) {
      X = x;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {    
      while (!start){
        try {
          wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      for (int i=1; i<21; i++) {
        System.out.print(X*i + " ");
          try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
          }
        }

        notifyAll();
      }
    }


    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        int inputT1 = 3;
        int inputT2 = 5;


        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1(inputT1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread2(inputT2));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you wait on some object and you notify on some object (in your current code you don't specify object, so it is `this`). As the result the Thread one calls notify on itself but no one is waiting for it. While the Thread2 is waiting on itself but no one wakes it (as no one calls notify on this instance of Thread2).

To wake the Thread2 up, you need to call notify on that object (its this) so your Thread1 should call obj.notify() (as obj is Thread2 in your code).

However it still won't work, as you do not pass the Thread2 instance to Thread1 (you just make a new one inside Thread1), so the thread2 you notify was just created and never started. The Thread2 from your main is started but it is never notified.

A possible fix to your code

```
static class Thread1 extends Thread {
private int X;
final Thread2 second;

public Thread1(int x,Thread2 second) {
 X = x;
 this.second = second;
}

public void run() {

    for(){
    //....    
    }

    second.start = true;
    second.notify();
}
}

static class Thread2 extends Thread {
private int X;
public boolean start = false;

public Thread2(int x) {
 X = x;
}

public void run() {

    while(!start){
        synchronized(this) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    for(){
        ....
    }
}
}


public static void main(String [ ] args)
{

        int inputT1 = 3;
        int inputT2 = 5;

        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(inputT2);
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(inputT1,t2);


        t1.start();
        t2.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wait()` and `notify()` method are low-level primitives, and are best avoided in favor of higher level concurrency APIs. Rolling your own concurrency code can be problematic (for instance, the `start` field in your code needs to be volatile!).

A simple fix would be to use `CountDownLatch`. Replace this:

```
private boolean start = false;
```

With this:

```
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

Then instead of calling `notifyAll()` you would call `latch.countDown();`

Thread2's `run` method would look like this:

```
public void run() {
  latch.await(); 

  for (int i=1; i<21; i++) {
    System.out.print(X*i + " ");
    try {
       Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
    }
  }

  threadMessage("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of 2 threads running one after another using lock/notify:

```
public class Thread2Test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Object sync = new Object();
    final Object lock = new Object();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                synchronized(sync) {
                    sync.notify(); // Notify main() to let it start t2.
                }

                for (int n=0; n<10; n++)
                {
                    System.out.println(n);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("t1 finished.");
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("t2 started...");
            synchronized(lock) {
                // don't need to do anything but wait for lock to be released
            }
            char c = 'a';
            for (int n=0; n<10; n++)
            {
                System.out.println(c);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                c++;
            }
            System.out.println("t2 finished.");
        }
    });

    try {
        System.out.println("Wait for t1 to start...");
        synchronized(sync) {
            t1.start();
            sync.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("end wait");
    t2.start();
}
```

Note that the sync object is used to guarantee that t1 will always start before t2.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Finally understood it! Sinceriously, thank you.